# Cannot install python3-uno in RHEL7.3(Maipo)

Tags: python-3.x

I am not being able to use the 'uno' and 'unotools'. This is the stack trace when I am trying to import it.

```
>>> from uno import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/uno/__init__.py", line 4, in 
<module>
from base import Element, Css, Payload, UnoBaseFeature, UnoBaseField
ImportError: cannot import name 'Element'
```

However the following are installed using pip3:

```
pip3 freeze
base==1.0.4
click==6.7
py==1.4.22
pytest==2.6.0
uno==0.3.3
unotools==0.3.3
```

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.3 (Maipo).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Actually, I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks for correcting me.